# Problems comparing two object variables

Tags: java, variables, object

I am doing a lab for college where I have to compare Moneybags. initially I instantiate them and add money etc. etc.I already have MoneyBag mb0, and mb1,but now I have to compare them with this code...it cannot be changed.

```
mb0.compare(mb1);
```

The class is MoneyBag. I need to return "Is Less Than","Is equal to", or "is Greater Than."
I currently have:

```
public int compare(MoneyBag mb1){
}
```

However, I cannot access mb0. I can access the int value of mb1. I need to compare them, print out the string literals, and obviously return the String. How would I do that? The top code cannot be changed, I have to make the second code work from it.

Comment: is it java ...? and how's your MoneyBag class set up?

Comment: Yes it is java. my code is set up with a custom construct, a default constructor, an add method, and this is the compare method that I cannot access mb0.add from. I have no clue what I am doing wrong....talk about frustration.  I do not know if my headers are incorrect "public int compare(MoneyBag mb1), that must be it, for I cannot access mb0 to compare the values of the add method

Comment: Inside the method, `this` will refer to `mb0` in the call statement.

Comment: You also can't return the ``String`` because the return value of the function is an ``int.`` You could however print the string, and return ``this.value-that.value`` where ``this`` is the object where the function is called, and ``that`` is a parameter of the compare function. The difference of the values should represent the comparison, a ``0`` would mean equal, negative less than and positive greater than.

Comment: @Chad It's better to return `int` and then let the caller do whatever it wants with the `int` (for example, examine the returned `int` and print out a `String`). It's also not good to print the string within the `compare` function. That is better done in the caller so that the `compare` function is modular (all it does is _compare_) and the caller can use the comparison result to decide on an action.

Comment: @ADTC I agree with this. I also think that returning int and deferring the responsibility of printing to the caller is the better solution

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the language, you should be able to access mb0 using something like in the body of your compare function.

```
return this.value - mb1.value;
```

Values of 0 represent "equal", values greater than 0 mean "Greater Than" and values less than 0 mean "Less Than";

Good luck

Comment: I cannot access: mb0.value

Comment: Sorry, meant mb1.value. Fixed

Comment: Note that `mb1` should be whatever the name is of the "formal" parameter.  It could be called with `mb10` as a parameter on the calling side but if the function header calls the parameter `potato`, that's what you use.

Comment: mb1 is the name of the "formal" parameter from the original question. You're right though, the parameter name doesn't necessarily match the variable name of the consumer.

Comment: I sense that the OP didn't understand this.